# VIM move in Insert mode

Tags: vim

**Why I ask:**

I use to enter code for example `if(condition){}`, in following step:

1. `if(){
   }`
2. move cursor back into `()` to complete condition
3. move cursor into `{}` to add task

I have read [Traversing text in Insert mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737163/traversing-text-in-insert-mode), and I add follow code into my `$HOME/.vimrc`

```
" key mapping
inoremap <A-h> <C-o>h
inoremap <A-j> <C-o>j
inoremap <A-k> <C-o>k
inoremap <A-l> <C-o>l
```

now I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, but the rest of two new map had no effect, then I test: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>, both of them work.

1. Is there any mistake when I do the key mapping?
2. How to check if my new mapping is conflicted with other or not?

**UPDATE: 2nd/Nov/2016**

---

1. I buy a new keyboard with cursor key...
2. Install [auto pair](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs)

However, I found one interesting thing, when I in Linux, there is ok for all above mapping just except <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>, because it conflicted with the ubuntu current open window help menu. I only meet my problem when I use ssh via `MobaXerm` application.

Comment: Why in all hell don't you simply use the cursor keys?

Comment: Are you using GVim or running command-line Vim from a terminal or terminal emulator?

Comment: @romainl becase my keyboard has no cursor keys....

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I use gvim via smartTTY

Comment: A keyboard without cursor keys? Are we in the 70's?

Comment: @romainl, I just bought a new keyboard with cursor key...

Comment: @romainl are you a vim user? if so- why would you even need the cursor keys? I always thought that vim is being chosen by people that do not want to move their hands all over their desk..

Comment: @lewiatan, how you move your cursor under insert mode?

Comment: I'm a Vim user, yes. And FWIW the top `vim` answerer on SO. Vim is chosen by people who value efficiency. Pressing `<Right>` is the most efficient way to move the cursor one character to the right in insert mode.

Comment: @romainl ok. no offence. But on the other hand I do not agree with that, because in my opinion moving your hand is not efficient (or maybe I should say ergonomic). I prefer using Ctrl + [ to leave the insert mode and move where I need to.

Comment: @HowChen I would: 1. Insert a template/frame of your condition. 2. Leave the insert mode with "Ctrl + [" 3. Move up and right with "k" and "w" 4. Start inserting condition with "a". 4. Repeat step 2 5. Start inserting below with "o". For more see my answer below.

Comment: Any way you look at it, `<Right>` is a lot more efficient than `<C-]>la` or whatever insert mode mapping you could come up with. Sure you need to move your hand a bit but it's actually a good thing for your fingers/hands/forearms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have read [Traversing text in Insert mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737163/traversing-text-in-insert-mode), and I add follow code into
>   my $HOME/.vimrc

You should carefully read the [accepted answer for that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1737259/717124), specially this part:

> The right way *is* to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, go where you want to do a
>   small correction, fix it, go back and keep editing.  It is effective
>   because Vim has much more movements than usual character
>   forward/backward/up/down.  After you learn more of them, this will
>   happen to be more productive.

The answer where you borrowed the mappings also mentions this:

> Notwithstanding what Pavel Shved said - that it is probably more
>   advisable to get used to Escaping Insert mode - here is an example set
>   of mappings for quick navigation within Insert mode: (...)

Anyway, if you want to understand the problem with the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, you should first ensure that the mapping is still defined in Vim (they could have been erased or overwritten). You can use `:imap` to list them; try these:

```
:imap <A-j>
:imap <A-k>
```

If your mappings are correctly defined each one will list its target (e.g.: `* <C-O>j`). In this case you should check if Vim is receiving these combinations correctly; try inserting then in the text (insert mode) by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> if you mapped that to paste from clipboard) and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> combinations. You can get more details at the [Vim FAQ "I am not able to create a mapping for the  key. What is wrong?"](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4).

**Edit**:

---

If your issue is mainly related with closing parenthesis, then there are several other options, which I believe that are more practical. I quick internet search returned the following:

- [SO - Automatic closing brackets for Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316727/automatic-closing-brackets-for-vim)
- [Vim wiki - Making Parenthesis And Brackets Handling Easier](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Making_Parenthesis_And_Brackets_Handling_Easier)
- [plugin - Auto Pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs)

Comment: But when I program, if I want to enter if(condition), I always like to enter if() first and then back to condition

Comment: @HowChen great that you posted an actual use case in this comment! I would recommend writing a macro, or googling a bit for "vim if parens" or something like that (doing that, I found https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs which may be what you want, or at least hopefully inspirational).

Answer (score 2):

I also think that you misuse Vim.

I know that the question was about something else but here is my idea of how you should move around in vim.

You have 3 steps:
1. Insert some empty loop / condition
2. Insert a condition
3. Insert a body of the loop / condition

This should represent 3 changes, each separated by leaving the insert mode.

To do it properly you can perform step 1 and then leave insert mode by using either <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (with the second one- which is also vim default- you do not have to reach for escape key).

Then you should navigate to the place where you want to insert your change using <kbd>h</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd> or <kbd>l</kbd> and follow it by starting insert mode.

There are several ways to start insert mode:

<kbd>I</kbd> - start insert mode at the beginning of the line (omitting whitespaces at the beginning)
<kbd>i</kbd> - start insert mode before the cursor
<kbd>a</kbd> - start insert mode after the cursor
<kbd>A</kbd> - start insert mode at the end of the line
<kbd>s</kbd> - change the sign under the cursor (can be combined with visual mode)
<kbd>c</kbd> - change text from under the cursor until place you have specified with the movement (e.g. ce - change until the end of the word, cl - the same as "s")
<kbd>C</kbd> - change everything from cursor until the end of the line
<kbd>S</kbd> - replace the whole line
<kbd>o</kbd> - start insert mode in the new line below
<kbd>O</kbd> - start insert mode in the new line above