# Remaping [ to { in vim

Tags: vim

I started working with VIM and I'm trying to configure it. Currently I want to remap `[` and `{`

So if I press `[` I get `{` without mashing shift. Right now I have it like this:

```
inoremap [ {                   
inoremap ] }
```

But it doesn't work. It just keeps on putting the `[`. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

I don't know if it matters but I'm using the auto-pairs plug-in.

EDIT
Just in case someone just wants to use it without any contiguration, here 
you go

```
ino " ""<left>
ino ' ''<left>
ino ( ()<left>
ino [ {}<left>
ino { []<left>
ino {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>0
ino {;<CR> {<CR>};<ESC>0
```

Taken from [Automatic closing brackets for Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316727/automatic-closing-brackets-for-vim/34992101#34992101) and slightly edited.

Comment: what does set paste? gives in your vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have turned on `set paste`.
if `set paste?` is showing `paste` as result. You can disable it by

```
:set nopaste
```

and try again.

More details at `help paste` and you may like `help pastetoggle` also.

Comment: Then I would doubt `auto-pairs`

Comment: i'll try deleting it when I get home

Comment: Yup. Autopairs was messing it up. Any idea if I can edit the plugin do I have to choose between them?

Comment: Instead of auto-pair, you can use/customise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316727/automatic-closing-brackets-for-vim/34992101#34992101

Comment: Ok this works for the normally mapped keys. I think I'll be able to take it from here. Thanks mate!