# gVim : Automatic annotation based on what is inserted

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I use gVim on Windows 10, mostly as a script editor for other languages. In some cases, I want automatic annotations for things that I annotate first. For instance, when writing LaTeX, I want Vim to annotate `\end{environment}` when I annotate `begin{environment}`, preferably without any extra input (but this doesn't really matter). I want to avoid entering normal mode every time I do this, so I want to use the `_vimrc` file instead. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you intend to do, this should be covered by one of the _AutoClose_ plugins mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316727/automatic-closing-brackets-for-vim).

Comment: Thanks for the link - I got the bracket autocomplete thing going thanks to the answers there. I'll tinker with it to make sure I can use it for other inputs as well.